# The value of boolean variable intialized in a class

Tags: c++

In my Class i have a boolean variable

```
class Sum_SystemTagControlVisitor : public FunctionVisitor
{
private:
    std::string variableName;
    std::string variableValue;
    std::string variableValue1;
    bool m_bIsTimer{ false };
public:
    Sum_SystemTagControlVisitor(std::string varName, std::string varValue ) : variableName(varName), variableValue(varValue) { }
    Sum_SystemTagControlVisitor(std::string varName, std::string varValue , bool isTimer) : variableName(varName), variableValue(varValue) , m_bIsTimer(isTimer){ }
    Sum_SystemTagControlVisitor(std::string varName, std::string varValue, std::string varValue1) : variableName(varName), variableValue(varValue), variableValue1(varValue1) { }
    virtual void visit(Sum_TagControl& tagControl ) override;

};
```

Only  one of the constructor is able to set the boolean value and for the other two constructors will it be always be false ?

Comment: The other two don't try to set the value. Why do you think they're not able to do it?

Comment: @
molbdnilo By that i mean that only in one constructor will i be setting the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inline initialization of member variables will always take place, unless your initializer list contains an entry for that variable.

So in short: For the constructor that doesn't initialize the variable, it will be automatically initialized to `false`.

Comment: perhaps worth mentioning that its called default member initializer. And the "default" is to suggest that its the initializer to be used when no other is present (or maybe not "default" is usually rather odd in C++ terminology)